# JQuery / JavaScript - trigger button click from another button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have this HTML which looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="savebutton" class="first button" />
<input type="submit" name="savebutton" class="second button" />
```

and JS:

```
jQuery("input.second").click(function(){
   // trigger second button ?
   return false;
});
```

So how can I trigger the click event from the 2nd button by clicking on the first one?
Note that I don't have any control over the 2nd button, neither on the html or the click event on it...

Comment: You say you have no control over the second button, why? is it in an `iframe` based on a different domain?

Comment: no, it's in the Wordpress core, and I don't want to modify code from it

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Add id's to both inputs, id="first" and id="second"

```
//trigger second button
$("#second").click()
```

Comment: I have an element on my page which does not have a click event, but if I click on it something happens. How can I just simulate the click without knowing wheter it is a mouseup, click or similar event?

Answer (score 30):

Well, you just fire the desired click event:

```
$(".first").click(function(){
    $(".second").click(); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 21):

```
jQuery("input.first").click(function(){
   jQuery("input.second").trigger("click");
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You mean this:

```
jQuery("input.first").click(function(){
   jQuery("input.second").trigger('click');
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

By using JavaScript:  `document.getElementById("myBtn").click();`

Answer (score 2):

If it does not work by using the `click()` method like suggested in the accepted answer, then you can try this:

```
//trigger second button
$("#second").mousedown();
$("#second").mouseup();
```

Answer (score 1):

this works fine, but file name does not display anymore.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("img.attach2").click(function(){ $("input.attach1").click(); return false; }); });
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript

> document.getElementById("myBtn").click();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!