# Click two buttons at the same time

Tags: jquery

I've got two submit buttons

```
<input id="button1" value="Subscribe" type="submit" name="signUp">
<input id="button2" value="Subscribe" type="submit" name="signUp">
```

What I want is when the user click the `#button1` the `#button2` will be clicked at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery / JavaScript - trigger button click from another button click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560227/jquery-javascript-trigger-button-click-from-another-button-click-event)

Comment: The form can only be submitted *once* - you can make it think it is the *other* button, but you can't "send both clicks" to the server without rewriting the form inputs and/or using an AJAX request.

Comment: @pst how would I do that in AJAX I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/hBTjA/

Comment: The two methods are to 1) create a new form, put the correct results in that (i.e. use a hidden field with the correct "submit value"), and then `submit()` it or 2) create an AJAX request (i.e. $.AJAX) and supply the desired data. The first approach causes an HTML form submission (and can send file contents) but the latter approach doesn't. However, since both submit button names/values are the same in the post, I wonder if that is really desired ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code :

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#button2").trigger('click');

})
```

Comment: It doesn't work user2063626 no button selected ..... how can i find that this button was presed ?