# I have implemented the answer that trigger another button click event but got some issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Related topic:
[JQuery / JavaScript - trigger button click from another button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560227/jquery-javascript-trigger-button-click-from-another-button-click-event)

```
<input type="submit" name="savebutton" id="first" />
<input type="submit" name="savebutton" id="second" />
```

and added this to my **first button** : `$("#second").click()`

**Functionality:** 1st button manually click then automatically triggered the 2nd button.

**Note:** *first* button has lots of database processing than *second* button. The second button processing logic is only to update things that the first button processed.

**Problem:**

It seems like the *second button* **surpasses** the first button processing because I have some SESSIONS initialized  and database update on first button but my 2nd button processing gets nothing to process. I mean sessions are not set and no db table updates were made.

**But** clicking the *first button* again (2nd time) my *second button* processing gets the **first** processed data/values (everything on my 1st click). I can tell that the data are coming from 1st click of the button because I also have some auto increment value on my db that increments for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly likely that what you are experiencing is an asynchronous request, where the second button is clicked by jquery before the first button functionality is really complete.

If this is the case the simplest solution is to use a callback on your async function (presumably an AJAX call), and use that callback to click the second button.

That's my intuition without code/fiddle, as async request are notorious for this kind of odd behavior.