# Trigger a button click with JavaScript on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Need Help in trigger a button click event from another button click. am using jquery fileuploader which doesn't look great on my web site so i've hidden the file upload control and put another button on top of it. Now i need to provoke that button by clicking on the dummy fileupload button thanks.

Comment: Did you do any research on the issue? What have you tried, and what's not working?

Comment: https://www.google.se/search?q=Trigger+a+button+click+with+JavaScript+on+button+click&oq=Trigger+a+button+click+with+JavaScript+on+button+click&aqs=chrome..69i57.635j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery / JavaScript - trigger button click from another button click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560227/jquery-javascript-trigger-button-click-from-another-button-click-event)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.trigger` and target your buttons ID:

```
$("#idOfButton").trigger("click");
```

Or the shorthand, just call a `click()` on your target

```
$("#idOfButton").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)

```
$("#button").on('click',function(){
     $('#fileUpload').trigger("click");
});
```