# Click a Button to pick Random other Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Bootstrap based OnePage-Website, primarly with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. On this website it is possible to book an appointment on a Team-Section, where I can choose one of three members by clicking on a button under their image. This Website should also include a Button in the Navigation. My Question is how would look the JavaScript or jQuery function, when I want to click on the Navigation-Button to pick randomly one of this three Buttons in the Team-Section? Not just to pick, also to execute.

Comment: Have you already tried anything? Can you show?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery / JavaScript - trigger button click from another button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560227/jquery-javascript-trigger-button-click-from-another-button-click-event)

Comment: don't bother to search. I'll do it for  you and then mark the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```js
function random_select(){
 var rnd=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);// from 0-2
 console.log('random=>'+rnd);
 $('[name="my_radio"]').eq(rnd).click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label><input name="my_radio" type="radio">test 1</label></br>
<label><input name="my_radio" type="radio">test 2</label></br>
<label><input name="my_radio" type="radio">test 3</label></br>

<input type="button" value="Auto select" onClick="random_select();">
```